# Filter out number from a specific line in log file

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have got a log file with specific String

```
"Received bla bla with count {} 23567"
```

Need to get the specific number which is at the end of line.
We can use awk or grep , not able to get this using below command.

```
grep "Received bla bla" logfile.log | grep '[0-9]'
```

Since the log file has timestamp at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk lets you easily grab the last element on a line.

```
awk '/Received bla bla/ { print $NF }' logfile.log
```

The variable `NF` contains the number of (by default, whitespace-separated) fields on the current line, and putting a dollar sign in front refers to the field with that index, i.e. the last field. (Conveniently, but slightly unusually for Unix tools, Awk indexing starts at 1, not 0.)

If the regex needs to come from a variable, try

```sh
awk -v regex='Received bla bla' '$0 ~ regex { print $NF }' logfile.log
```

The operator `~` applies the argument on the right as a regex to the argument on the left, and returns a true value if it matches. `$0` is the entire current input line.  The `-v` option lets you set the value of an Awk variable from outside Awk before the script begins to execute.

Answer (score 2):

GNU grep with PCRE matching:

```
grep -Po 'Received .* with count .*?\K\d+' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/Received bla bla.* //p'
```

Comment: Weird .., This is the question where the Awk regulars have a `sed` battle, and I'm the only one with an Awk answer.

Comment: @tripleee You already had the best awk answer so I upvoted yours and posted a sed alternative since it's not totally out of the question to use sed for this and the existing sed answers won't work (they'll print every line) and aren't portable to all POSIX seds.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. I am on mobile so couldn't test it as of now, these should work but.

```
sed -E 's/.*([0-9]+$)/\1/' Input_file
```

In case you want to print digits  coming at last of line by searching a specific text on that line then try like:

```
sed -E '/text to search/s/.*([0-9]+$)/\1/' Input_file
```